# How to pass file descriptor from UsbDeviceConnection to native code on Android?

Tags: android, file, android-ndk, java-native-interface

According to the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getFileDescriptor() returns file descriptor which can be used in native code. How can i pass it to native code (as to child process or via JNI)?

Comment: Pass it through JNI as an int, which will be a jint on the native side which you can trivially cast to an int.  To get it to a child process it would perhaps be easier to pass it first and have it inherited (check for close on exec) or else use the special feature of unix domain sockets or Binder for passing "live" file descriptors.

Comment: Could you use the read/write sys calls with that fd? I did the same but using JNI to get it. But for some reason when I use read() I get EINVAL (22) which means Invalid Argurment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNIX Socket if you want to pass in to child process or just as int via JNI